# cocoaPods pod install Permission denied

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

This is the short version:

When I run

```
pod install
```

in an Xcode project I get

> [!] Pod::Executable pull error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD:
>   Permission denied

If I run

```
sudo pod install
```

I get no error, but my files installed are owned by root and can't compile and I have to `chown` those files to a normal user to use the Xcode compiler.

I am running Lion OSX.

I installed cocoaPods using

```
sudo gem install cocoaPods
```

I had to use `sudo` because without it I got

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>
> You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.

so now I have a root installed version of cocoaPods that downloads root owned Xcode libraries.

Is `sudo` installation of cocoaPods the wrong way or normal way?

If normal, is there a way to fix the pod install problem?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I solved this problem by running the following command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

and

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cocoapods
```

Please replace `username` and `groupname` with your Mac login username/groupname.

Comment: Note, you need to have the username you are transferring ownership to between the -R and ~filename

Comment: to @lehn0058, I am sorry to missing the username parameter in a hurry.

Comment: As a side note, the incident occurred because i ran 'sudo pod setup' instead of 'pod setup'.

Comment: You should be able to replace `username.groupname` with `$USER` and it should work with a straight copy paste for anyone. Worked a charm anyway thanks.

Comment: Should it not be username:groupname instead of username.groupname?

Comment: @Adam Good question, they are equal(the same effect)

Comment: Missed the 5 minute edit window when i borked but: The owner and group operands are both optional; however, at least one must be specified.  If
     the group operand is specified, it must be preceded by a colon (``:'') character.

Comment: To know your username just type: `whoami`

Comment: This solved the problem. Finally I was able to add pods. this answer saved my time. cocoapods installation is sometimes very tricky !!.

Comment: To automatically fetch username run

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`

and
 
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.cocoapods`

Answer (score 22):

I only used (where `username` is your Mac login username)

```
sudo chown -R username ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

and

```
sudo chown -R username ~/.cocoapods
```

when I tried with the groupname parameter I got

```
chown: username.groupname: illegal user name
```

Of course I used my own username and groupname :)

Comment: I have resolved the issue by removing the content in the ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods and then go to the project directory and pod install

Answer (score 11):

Removing the directories worked for me:

```
sudo rm -R  ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
sudo rm -R  ~/.cocoapods/repos
```

If some other problems still exist.

Remove the Pods directory and the podFile.lock file.

Cocoapods just adds the directories again.

Comment: `~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub` does not exist.

Comment: which version of CocoaPods do you have?

Answer (score 6):

It's just need to add permission flag `--user-install`

For updating use:
`sudo gem update --user-install`

And for installing use: 
`sudo gem install --user-install cocoapods`

Comment: its work for me after add permission flag --user-install in macos ventura 13.0.1

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with Mac OS X's default installation of Ruby. The Ruby/Gems installation is owned by root in the location you specified.

This is normal behavior *unless* you install a Ruby manager. I would recommend [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) but [RVM](https://rvm.io/) is popular as well.

These installed your Ruby installation in your `$HOME` folder. This way your user owns the Ruby and gem executables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I did find a work around, chown user ~/.cocoapod/master/git/FETCH_HEAD, this made my problem go away but I will look into the rbenv or RVM solution

Comment: for my quick workaround I also had to change permissions of ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub, now it works but still a hack

Comment: To be clear, you need to use sudo to install the gem unless you are using a Ruby manager. The other issues that you had are not expected and could have been caused by running `sudo pod setup` or `sudo pod install`.

Comment: Thanks Fabio, I never ran pod setup, but when I run sudo pod install it creates root owned libs which wont compile.  Also update to my quick fix,   I had to chown everything under ~/.cocoapod/master/git/ I  tested that and it works ok.  I will look into the pod setup and the Ruby manager.

Answer (score 4):

With all the errors that I got while installing CocoaPods in some of my projects, I've finally succeeded in finding a pattern with it. Here it is:

1. Access your project folder from the terminal:

   ```
   $ cd /Users/username/Downloads/MessagesTableViewController-master
   ```
2. Create a podfile:

   ```
   $ touch podfile
   $ open -e podfile
   ```
3. After the podfile is created, access it via the Finder and edit it in any other text editor except TextEdit because TextEdit sometimes messes up with apostrophes in the pod file. I used textWrangler. Write the following in the pod file; (Note these dependencies are for projects that support iOS version 6.0 and above)

   ```
   platform :ios, '6.0'
   pod 'AFNetworking'
   ```
4. Save the file and close it.
5. Go back to the terminal and see your pod version:

   ```
   $ pod --version
   ```

   Depending on your pod version, if an update is required, run this command:

   ```
   $ sudo gem update
   ```
6. After the update completes, or it states that it is already up-to-date, you should install the cocoapods:

   ```
   $ sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```
7. And at the very end, just run the following commands:

   ```
   $ sudo pod setup
   $ sudo pod install
   ```

And Viola! It is done. You'll see a Pods named folder within your project folder and the dependency you stated in the pod file will be apparent in Pods folder as a sub-folder.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick, easy, hacky solution:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.cocoapods
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the original question:

```
Is sudo installation of cocoaPods the wrong way or normal way?
```

When I do a `pod install` I get:

```
Analyzing dependencies
CocoaPods 0.36.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
```

so I assume `sudo` is OK.

Comment: Your use of sudo would be to install an update to cocoapods itself, which is necessary. Sudo is not okay for 'sudo pod install', as it produces the error:  [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. There's more on the [CocoaPods official web-site](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing the most up to date version of Ruby. Instructions here: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra 
I was then able to successfully run
sudo gem update
sudo gem install cocoapods