# CocoaPods `pod install` error: cannot open FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Tags: git, cocoapods

My question is quite similar to this other [1] (but I open a new one as the accepted answer on it doesn't seem to work for me).

Put it short, when I run `pod install` I always get this error: `[!] Pod::Executable remote update - error: cannot open FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied`.

As I read that other question, I started to use RVM and actually when I run `which ruby` I get `/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby` and I've double and triple checked I'm the total owner of all that installation. No root there.

As I've also read the problem may have something to do with Git, I also updated it and when I run `which git` I get `/usr/local/git/bin/git` and I'm also the total owner of that. No root there either.

In question [1], user1054503 commented he solved same problem chown'ing `/Users/myuser/.cocoapods/master` so I've also tried that, but nothing seems to work. So I'm basically stuck.

Any idea anyone, please?

[1] [cocoaPods pod install Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049335/cocoapods-pod-install-permission-denied)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I’m guessing it’s your cache, which is located in `~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`. Try chown’ing that as well.

Comment: Absolutely! I missed that (shame on me)! Huge thanks again for your time and work! :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and resolved it by chown'ing `~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/` **and** `~/.cocoapods`.

Comment: if no file found occur then try ~/Library/Caches. This will also work and then 
~/.cocoapods.