# Can't run sudo pod install after updating to cocoapods 0.32.1 with error "You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I found an issue when running sudo pod install command after updating it to latest version 0.32.1. Earlier it was working very fine.

When I tried to do pod install with older cocoapods, it asked me to update to latest cocoapods version i.e. 0.32.1. After I updated by cocoapods gem, I can't do sudo pod install in my Xcode project. It gives me following error.

```
± sudo pod install                                                                                                            ruby-1.9.3-p0
Password:
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/claide-0.5.0/lib/claide/command.rb:328:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)

CocoaPods, the Objective-C library package manager.

Commands:....
```

Any suggestion to overcome the issue would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AndyTsen Just posted an answer, let me know if it works for you

Comment: that seemed to do the trick. Thanks man!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had to update permission on CocoaPods

> sudo chown -R $USER ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
>
> sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cocoapods

Since it seems to fix the problem for some people, you might want to try running "pod install" and see if it fixed your problem from that point. However, I still had a permission denied when running "pod install" for a pod item, so running the next line will overwrite permission for the pod folder.

> sudo chown -R $USER ./Pods

I have removed the old podfile.lock before running pod install

Source :

[cocoaPods pod install Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049335/cocoapods-pod-install-permission-denied)

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/509

Answer (score 10):

I am working with windows.  After reading all tips which didn't work I drove into the code base.
As a disclaimer, I am beginning phase of developing an app and my goal is to get a quick proof of concept.  Therefore, this solution will only bypass that the error message as a quick hack.

In the file ~/lib/cocoapods/command.rb you will find a function on line 47 that stops the program if there is a root user.

```
#help! 'You cannot run CocoaPods as root.' if Process.uid == 0
```

Simply comment out the line.  Again, this is a terrible idea to do in any situation except as a pragmatist using Windows and trying to get proof of concept out.

Answer (score 7):

In m1 MACs run `sudo arch -x86_64 pod install --allow-root` to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing worked for me except the following

1. switched to ios platform with `cd platforms/ios`
2. switched ownership of the folder to the current user with `sudo chown -R YourUsername .`
3. Pod install

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the both "folder content project" and file "project.xcodeproj" was locked "i ignore why !!! maybe the git clone provoked error :s", i unlock the folder and apply all changes for sub folder .... And it WORK FINE :D