# You cannot run CocoaPods as root (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, firebase, cocoapods

I'm setting up a new react-native firebase project following the 'Getting Started' section of https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter

All of the Android steps work fine but I'm struggling to get the iOS pod install to work (step 1.4 `[iOS] cd ios and run pod install`)

I've installed ruby and used gem to install cocoapods like:

`gem install cocoapods`

I accepted all the defaults and the installation was successful but now when I run any pod command I get an error.

Running `pod --version` gives me:

`` Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
        3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help) ``

I'm running Windows 10 Pro

There is a stack overflow answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37451422/3368558 which bypasses this by commenting out the check but I'm looking for a more correct approach which doesn't involve me messing with CocoaPods itself.

Comment: Hi, did you find one? Thanks

Comment: No luck yet, I decided to go a different route and deploy using Expo and a VM running Apple.

Comment: i installed the pre-release version and i dont see this error