# "GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h" file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, google-signin

I am using Ionic with the google Plus cordova plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/google-plus/

I set up everything correctly and it works without any problems on Android. 
On iOS I used the command "Ionic cordova prepare iOS", at first I got problems with some Cocoapods ("cannot run cocoapods as root"), I fixed that Error with the help of this post: [Can't run sudo pod install after updating to cocoapods 0.32.1 with error "You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190064/cant-run-sudo-pod-install-after-updating-to-cocoapods-0-32-1-with-error-you-ca). After that I was able to get a .xcodeproj.

After some research I found out I have to open the .xcworkspace.
I clicked on run and got the Error: "GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h" file not found

Comment: I am stuck on this for a while now

Answer (score 7):

Uninstall plugin : `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-googleplus`

Install plugin version 7.0.1: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus@7.0.1`

This will fix your problem reason being version 7.0.1 doesn't use POD dependencies.

Comment: This fix the issue but because of this getting UIWebView issue app upload time

Answer (score 2):

Solution: downgrade cordova-plugin-googleplus to version 7.0.2

Comment: This fix the issue but because of this getting UIWebView issue app upload time

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firebase make sure that your podfile is not written GoogleUtilities, if so delete it, and leave only GooglePlus. Then give

```
pod install
```

to the root of your project and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted the answer from ch3t. However on installing you need to supply the app specific variables as seen below. For reference visit the link https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/blob/master/README.md#4-installation-phonegap-cli--cordova-cli

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus@7.0.2 --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid --variable WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID=mywebapplicationclientid
```

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered with the same problem and solved it by this:

[image: Copy ios/RNGoogleSignin into Libraries folder in Xcode]

- Copy ios/RNGoogleSignin into Libraries folder in Xcode

[image: Add this line to Framework Search Paths in Build Settings: $(PROJECT_DIR)/GoogleSDK]

- Add this line to Framework Search Paths in Build Settings:

  $(PROJECT_DIR)/GoogleSDK

[image]

- Remove libRNGoogleSign.a from Link Binary With Libraries in Build
  Phases:
- And lastly clean your build folder and build.

Credits to: [taingmeng](https://github.com/taingmeng)

Answer (score -3):

I used an old mac, that was the problem