# You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help) Flutter

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

So Hello,

I know there are many similar Questions but only a few of them a specifically for Flutter.

**My Problem:**
I want to run my Flutter project but then this error shows up:

```
CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
```

Then i install cocoapods with this commant:

```
udo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

However if i want to run:

```
pod install
```

it show this error:

```
[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)
```

Thanks for any answer stackoverflow is my last hope
LG

**Solution**

Just run this command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

and then:

```
pod setup
```

and

```
pod install
```

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190064/cant-run-sudo-pod-install-after-updating-to-cocoapods-0-32-1-with-error-you-ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

Just run this command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

and then:

```
pod setup
```

and

```
pod install
```