Getting error when install pod (macbook M1)
I am getting error when installing pod for my project.
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.1.4/lib/bigdecimal.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.1.4/lib/bigdecimal.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.1.4/lib/bigdecimal.bundle' (no such file), '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.1.4/lib/bigdecimal.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.1.4/lib/bigdecimal.bundle (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.1.4/lib/bigdecimal.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.2/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/array.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.2/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.2/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:3:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.2/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

I am installing the pods on my project but it gives above error. Please help me fix this. I am using M1 machine using Xcode version 15.1. When I install pod it us using my systems ruby, I have already have renv ruby on other path but it take systems ruby everytime.

which command did you execute? pod install? Can you show your Podfile?

I have execute 'pod install'.

You installed bigdecimal outside of Rosetta but you're now trying to run it inside Rosetta. Why?

Can you help me understand it, I am not sure how to revert it.

Use this;
sudo arch -x86_64 pod install --allow-root

Thanks Lalith:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71488298/1821855
