# Use sudo for gem install cocoapods

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I run

```
$ gem install cocoapods
```

I get

```
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I've read this post [cocoaPods pod install Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049335/cocoapods-pod-install-permission-denied) 
but the answer there doesn't say whether it is correct to run `sudo` on your `gem install` (despite being asked in the Question - i.e. Is sudo installation of cocoaPods the wrong way or normal way? ).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you are not using any package manager. Since, you don't have write permission to this directory, there is nothing wrong in using `sudo` for `gem install`.

However, I prefer changing ownership of that directory, so that I don't have to use `sudo` every time.
i.e. `sudo chown -R [login name] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0`

and ensure that I have write permission. `sudo chmod -R u+w /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0`

Consider using `rvm` (ruby version manager) or `rbenv`

Comment: I _am_ using rvm. Why does it seem like I'm not?

Comment: Well, in that case, I would recommend using `rvmsudo` instead of just `sudo`. Check out this link for further details: https://rvm.io/integration/sudo

Comment: you can use ```sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0``` for direct copy/paste

Answer (score 13):

```
 sudo gem install cocoapods
```

works for me

Comment: You shouldn't use sudo for that. It's better to fix the underlying problem, see other accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution when you are receiving the "Operation not permitted" error.

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/Software/ruby
$ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby
$ gem install cocoapods
[...]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to 'update Gems'. Open terminal, then do this

```
sudo gem update
```

That's enough.