# How to get rid of warning during rails server start up: "Warning: Running `gem pristine --all`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run "gem pristine -all", I get:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
>       Operation not permitted

A similar post suggested creating a file:

```
# /tmp/dirty.rb
require 'shellwords'


    Gem::Specification.stubs.reject(&:stubbed?).reject(&:default_gem?).each do |gemspec|
      puts "gem pristine #{Shellwords.escape gemspec.name} --version #{Shellwords.escape gemspec.version.to_s}"
    end
```

Then running it from command:

```
ruby /tmp/dirty.rb | bash
```

When I tried this, I get error:

> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
>   directory

Any ideas?

Comment: add the solutions that you tried in the question instead of just a link.

Comment: Please read "[ask]".

Comment: @theTinMan -- Ok, I'll reread.

Comment: @KPrince36 - Better? or more room for improvement?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permission error running the install. Try running `sudo chown -R [login name] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0` from the command line to give you ownership of the directory. Then `sudo chmod -R u+w /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0` to ensure you have read/write access. See [Use sudo for gem install cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741322/use-sudo-for-gem-install-cocoapods) question which addressed this issue.