# Getting a "don't have write permissions" when installing cocoapod

Tags: ruby, swift, macos, cocoapods, rvm

I'm trying to put a google sign in for my ios app and to do that I need CocoaPods. But when installing it like there own website on terminal I get this:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods

[Password: (*Put in my admin password for my macbook*)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

This is being done on a Macbook Air running High Sierra 10.13.2
(Don't know if you need that info but I've never done anything with cocoapods or ruby before)

I also tried following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741322/use-sudo-for-gem-install-cocoapods) and followed the awnser and installed RVM, or at least I think I did. I just put this in:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Well I tried installing CocoaPods after that but still got the same thing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You might try the following command

`sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin`

---

The problem is that `gem install` was trying to use `/usr/bin` for installing the binaries, which shouldn't be touched for the [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection). Since:

> A centerpiece is the protection of system-owned files and directories
>   against modifications by processes without a specific "entitlement",
>   even when executed by the root user or a user with root privileges
>   (sudo)

Sudo is without any power in this situation.

Hence the solution uses `-n`, from `gem help install` it says:

> -n, --bindir DIR  Directory where binary files are located

in this way you will be able to move the binaries in a more comfortable destination: `/usr/local/bin` which stands for programs that a normal user may run.

Comment: Looks good. Just to make sure that everything is right, is this what it's supposed to look like? :                                                               
`Successfully installed cocoapods-1.3.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.3.1
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 3 seconds
1 gem installed `                                                                                         
It took only a couple of seconds and I heard it takes awhile. And if it is correct, thank you!

Comment: This worked for me, i've run command sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin and installed

Comment: Saved me. Installing react native was failing on the cocoapod step. This fixed it. Thank you!