# What privileges do I lose when I install cocoapods without sudo?

Tags: ios, ruby, installation, cocoapods

I want to install CocoaPods, but I don't have an administrator account, meaning I can't use sudo. Can I install CocoaPods without `sudo`, and if I can what privileges do I loose?

### Update

I tried `gem install cocoapods --user-install` and I got this output:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/yaml.rb:4:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/psych-2.0.13/psych.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libruby.2.2.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/psych-2.0.13/psych.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/psych-2.0.13/psych.bundle
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/psych-2.0.13/lib/psych.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/yaml.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:624:in `load_yaml'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:328:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

The other solution of installing RVM I looked into, but I had trouble installing it. (Maybe because I'm not an admin?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [cocoaPods pod install Permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049335/cocoapods-pod-install-permission-denied)

Comment: @Hackerman, thanks for the link. The reason those solutions won't help me is because they all require sudo, since I don't have an administrator account I can't use sudo. The other solution of installing RVM I looked into, but I had trouble installing it. (Maybe because I'm not an admin?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at cocoapods documentation:
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#sudo-less-installation

Comment: I look at that, and I was kind of confused, do I just copy and paste the commands into terminal? And is there anything I can't do with cocoapods because of not using sudo?